# jQuery FancyBox not loading YouTube URL

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using fancyBox for accessing a YouTube URL from a database. I can get the popup to work, and the fade overlay - but I see no video start to play? If I open the link in a new tab or window it plays? Here is my code:

```
<a class="fancybox various fancybox.iframe" href="GENERATED YOUTUBE LINK"><img class="recipe_pic " src="_resources/images/SRC FOR IMAGE"></a>

Script: 

<script> jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox(); });        

jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery(".various").fancybox({ maxWidth : 800, 
maxHeight : 600, fitToView : false, width : '70%', height : '70%', autoSize : false, 
closeClick : false, openEffect : 'none', closeEffect : 'none' }); }); </script>
```

Comment: Could we see your script?

Comment: there I added my jQuery script - I swapped out the $ for jQuery - since I am using it on a php page pulling from a database using the $ (unless there is a better way I should do that as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit and got it running on JSFiddle. Make sure the YouTube URL that's generated uses the `/embed` URL and not `/watch` I am not sure it is working as it should, please confirm or deny.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="fancybox various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?autoplay=true"><img class="recipe_pic " src="http://www.shoemycolor.com/media/wysiwyg/365984-gangnam-style.jpg"></a>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox(); 
});        

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery(".various").fancybox({ 
        maxWidth : 800, 
        maxHeight : 600, 
        fitToView : false, 
        width : '70%', 
        height : '70%', 
        autoSize : false, 
        closeClick : false, 
        openEffect : 'none', 
        closeEffect : 'none' 
    }); 
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhKF2/)

Comment: YES! It works! I believe they are all using the /watch URL so that must have been the main issue, and I should have thought to check that I guess! Thank you a ton.

Comment: No problem at all, glad you got it sorted!

Comment: @jacob : you can keep using the `/watch?v=VIDEO_ID` format **IF** you include the fancybox media helper, which will make the conversion to the `embed` format to display the video inside an iframe

Comment: @JFK That's good to know too. I'll take a look - since a lot of these are already in the database and pre-filled.

Comment: @jacob : Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples ==> Extended Functionality ==> Media Helper (3rd set of tabs) for demo and html and js code. **Notice** that the first youtube example uses the format `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not attribute `href="#"`, or just bind `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` on click. So when you click it will not add in browser tab link field `/#`